# Time evolution of two orthogonal states in Time Dependent Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory

Given the two orthogonal states for $H_0$ , $|n(t)>_I, |m(t)>_I$, in the interaction picture, we want to find the probability of transforming from one to the other after time t, aka:

$ \ (1) \ |<n(t)|m(t)>|^2$.

Naively, I would think to do this:

$ \ (2) \ |<n(t)|m(t)>|^2 = |<n(0)|U_I^\dagger U_I|m(0)>|^2 = |<n(0)|m(0)>|^2 = \delta_{nm}$

Where

$U_I = exp[\frac{-i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^{t} d\tau e^{\frac{i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}V(\tau)e^{\frac{-i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}]$

and V is the perturbation (and is hermitian). (U is unitary)

Using the perturbation theory I would get $\delta_{nm}$ for the 0th and 1st order, but for the second order, I get something completely different.
Which way is the correct way to go, and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your operator $\hat U_I$ a unitary operator? You didn't say much about this operator.

Comment: $\hat{U_I}$ is the time evolution operator in the interaction picture. I'm guessing that it is unitary, otherwise there would be a whole lot of problems with the preservation of probability (non unitary operators do not conserve norm).

Comment: but, under a unitary transformation, two orthogonal states remain orthogonal. I suppose that it is known to you. Then, what is the question? Where appears the perturbation in your equations? (I just added numbering, for easiness of referring to them)

Comment: I rephrased - i'm not sure whether or not U is unitary.

Comment: No, if you are not sure about unitarity, there are two possibilities: 1) check by yourself if the unitarity though holds, or use indeed the perturbation calculus. But, in your place, and for your specific problem, I would first check unitarity.

Comment: OK, so I got that U is unitary, so this means the perturbation theory method is not correct?

Comment: It is not exact as an exact treatment. If $\hat U$ is unitary, then unitarity preserves orthogonality, this is one of the features of unitary transformations. But, may I know how did you prove unitarity of $\hat U$ ?

Comment: Is $V$ just a potential?

Comment: Yes, and it is hermitian

Comment: then, please tell me, how did you prove that $\hat U_I$ is unitary? I don't ask this for nothing, there is a trick there.

Comment: $(\int e^{\frac{iH_0 t}{\hbar}} V e^{\frac{-iH_0 t}{\hbar}})^\dagger = \int (e^{\frac{-iH_0 t}{\hbar}})^\dagger V^\dagger (e^{\frac{iH_0 t}{\hbar}})^\dagger = \int e^{\frac{iH_0 t}{\hbar}} V e^{\frac{-iH_0 t}{\hbar}}$

since this is hermitian, the exponent is unitary.

Comment: yes, but you have to show that $\hat U_I^\dagger \ \hat U_I = 1$. Is it trivial? No, it isn't. Please multiply $\hat U_I^\dagger$ and $\hat U_I$ and show that you get 1.

Comment: ok, so I have $\hat{U_I} = e^{iH}$, where H is something Hermitian.
$\hat{U_I}^\dagger = e^{-iH}$
and:
$\hat{U_I}^\dagger \hat{U_I} = e^{-iH+iH} = 1$

Comment: What I was trying to say was that you got until now $\hat U_I \dagger \hat U_I = exp[\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^{t} d\tau e^{\frac{i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}V(\tau)e^{\frac{-i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}] \cdot exp[\frac{-i}{\hbar} \int_{t_0}^{t} d\tau e^{\frac{i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}V(\tau)e^{\frac{-i H_0 \tau}{\hbar}}]$. Though it's not trivial that the result is 1. There is a detail to be paid attention, $e^{\hat A} \ e^{\hat B}$ where $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ are two operators, in general is not equal to $e^{\hat A + \hat B}$ unless $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ commute. So, is this condition fulfilled?

Comment: Every operator commutes with itself.

Comment: Well, if the two exponents commute, you can add them, the result is zero, and $e^0 = 1$. Only now the unitarity was proved. And now we can use its property of conserving orthogonality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion lies with the definition of the transition probability.

The transition amplitude between an $H_0$ eigenstate $H_0 \left|m\right> = E_m \left|m\right>$ and another eigenstate $H_0 \left|n\right> = E_n \left|n\right>$ due to a perturbation $V$ after a time $t$ is given by
\begin{align}
\left< n \right| U(t) \left| m \right> & = \left< n \right| e^{-iH_ot/\hbar} U_I(t) \left| m \right> \\
& = e^{-iE_n t/\hbar} \left< n \right|U_I(t) \left| m \right> \\
& = e^{-iE_n t/\hbar} \left< n \right| U_I(t) \left| m \right> = e^{-iE_n t/\hbar} \langle n | m(t) \rangle_I.
\end{align}
Up to first order, we find
\begin{equation}
\langle n | U_I(t) | m \rangle \simeq \delta_{nm} - \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^t dt' \langle n | V_I(t') | m \rangle.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The perturbation theory is an approximation. If you can do your calculus exactly, don't use approximations.
Your equality (2) can be exact, though, ***on condition*** that $\hat U_I$ is a transformation that preserves inner product. The simplest thing is to check whether $\hat U_I$ is unitary, that would be satisfactory, because a unitary transformation has a property that it preserves the inner product. So, two orthogonal states remain orthogonal.

A remark : I don't say that the unitary transformation is the only one that has the property of conserving the inner product. Other transformation may have this property too. I just said the unitary transformation has this property.

**NOTE (Truax' theorem)** : this is a useful theorem when checking unitarity. The product of two exponential operators $e^{\hat A}$ and $e^{\hat B}$ is not equal, in general, with $e^{\hat A + \hat B}$. This equality holds only if $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ commute. The theorem says,

$$ e^{\hat A} e^{\hat B} = e^{\hat A + \hat B + f(\hat A, \ \hat B, \ [\hat A, \hat B])}$$

where $f$ is a function of the mentioned arguments, and one case in which $f = 0$ is when $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ commute.

Comment: As long as it is not clear whether $\hat U$ is unitary, my post is not a sure answer, so I delete it.

Comment: The question is why is the perturbation theory method incorrect. Where is the problem with it?

Comment: @golanor - I am skeptical about the theory of perturbation being incorrect. If you can show your calculus, we can see what you did.